# Can EE Extensions be used for CE?

Tags: magento2, extensions, magento-community, magento-2-commerce

I've seen a lot of discussion about whether or not CE extensions can be used for EE, but there isn't much in terms of clarification for the reverse scenario.

We're currently on EE and starting a migration to CE and we have a few EE extensions that the providers have no been willing to provide us the CE version but instead wanting us to buy the extension again in CE version (typical money grab from extension providers).

Does anyone have any experience in this and have you ran into any compatibility issues when trying to use EE extensions with CE platform?

Answer (score 1):

**NO.**

Since EE extension might be referencing some of the classes that only exist in EE.

You could install it and see if it breaks or behaves differently than what it is supposed to do.

But this will always add complexity to your codebase since every time you are updating the module, you will have to do thorough testing.

I wouldn't recommend using EE extensions in Community instance.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, will take into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

There are following points you need to consider while use `EE` to `CE`.

1. Your third party extension use some of the classes which only available into EE, then extension not working into CE.
2. Your third party extension depend on EE default extension which not available into CE, so that can't work on CE.
3. If extension use database fields which only available into EE, then that not work into CE.

Lastly I said that, extension is work or not into CE that depend on how extension is developed.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, will take into consideration.

Comment: If answer help, upvote and accept as solution, so it will help other in community.